# Opencart Journal Theme Upgradation, Mobile App and Multi Vendor Marketplace Issues

Tags: php, html, css, opencart-3, journal

I have opencart version 3.0.2.0 with default theme. I want to upgrade it to journal theme. I have journal versions 3.0.3.1, 3.0.3.4,3.0.3.7,3.1.3 and 3.1.4. I would upgrade default theme to any one of these journal themes. I want to make a mobile app of my site as well with any one of the above journal themes. I want also to use multi vendor marketplace with these themes. But I have a confusion. I have searched for mobile app builders on net. These builders show that they would build a mobile app with featuers of their own different from the front end and back end of my default theme or different from the front end and back end of my journal theme. I want to build a mobile app which should have the same featurs, front end and back end as that of my default theme or that of my journal theme. Please refer me some free mobile app builders which are compatible with the journal theme or default theme and can convert the journal theme or default theme with front end and back end as it appears on desktop into a mobile app which has same features as a website has features when it runs on desktop or laptop. Please refer me some free multi vendor market places as well which are compatible with the journal theme or deault theme and can also be used in mobile app. I would be thankful for any reply.

Comment: I would not recommend to use the Journal theme. While it looks impressive at first glance, it is also the worst theme of all time. This theme destroys the OC framework. And I don't think it will work with the multivendor extension. Before use this theme, please read OC forum regarding such.

Comment: I am thankful @K.B. for your kind reply. Please suggest me some free opencart themes which can work with multivendor extensions and can be converted into mobile app. I had asked another question. I want to convert my website with all its features, front end and back end into mobile app. I want my mobile app should have same feaures, front end and back end as my website has. Please suggest me some free or cheap mobile app builders and some free or cheap multivendor extensions which can work with your suggested themes. Thanks

Comment: You should  choose multivendor extension and next ask them (devs of the multivendor) which theme is the best to work with that multivendor extension.